# Is there something like a metric that only knows about angles?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, geometric-topology

Please excuse the unclarity in the question title but I don't know how to call the object I am looking for yet. My idea is that a metric on some topological space introduces a notion of lengths and angles and that there should be some other mathematical object that introduces a notion of angle only. (Such an object could among other things be of use to describe theories that are invariant under conformal transformations like electrodynamics.)

I thought about defining an object that is the equivalence class of some metric under conformal transformations but that seems quite involved. Is there a more basic notion?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes, it's called a conformal structure. Defining it as a conformal class of Riemannian metrics is the simplest definition (there are alternatives, but you would need to know what a principal fiber bundle is).

Comment: @MoisheCohen Thank you! I will look for conformal structures right away! I am open to and curious about suggestions involving principal fiber bundles!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are sufficiently comfortable with fiber bundles, you can read a very abstract definition of a conformal structure, for instance, in this book:

S.Kobayashi, ["Transformation Groups in Differential Geometry"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3540586598).

In short, a conformal structure is a reduction of the structure group of the frame bundle of a smooth $n$-manifold $M$ from $GL(n,{\mathbb R})$ to the "conformal group" $CO(n):={\mathbb R}_+\cdot O(n)$.

For comparison, a Riemannian metric on $M$ can be defined as a reduction of the structure group from $GL(n,{\mathbb R})$ to $O(n)$.

The two notions are related through the fact that $CO(n)/O(n)\cong {\mathbb R}_+$, which is contractible. In concrete terms, this means that every conformal structure on $M$ can be defined as a conformal equivalence class of Riemannian metrics on $M$.